# Error when click menu item android

Tags: android, database, click, menuitem

I wanna replace all button functions with click on menu item, but when I clicked menu item, I got error, below is my source code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {         
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menuclearcontainer:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            ListView listitem = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listitem);

            dbHelper.openDataBase();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // LINE 526
            String SQL = "DELETE FROM itemchecked";
            db.execSQL(SQL);

            try
            {
                final ArrayList<ItemDetail_class> itemlist = dbHelper.getAllItem(tseparate, tgroup);
                listitem.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getBaseContext(), itemlist));               

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selection has been cleared !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }           

            return true;

        case R.id.menuaddcontainer:
return true;
      }
}
```

for the error :

```
06-02 15:02:08.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15040): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 15:02:08.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15040):    at com.example.app.ViewDetail.onOptionsItemSelected(ViewDetail.java:526)
06-02 15:02:08.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15040):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2606)
```

I have button with above function (on menuclearcontainer), and it works normally, but if I switch to put in MenuItem, it will be error. Do you have any solutions ?

Comment: where is  `dbHelper` initialized?

Comment: @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_detail);
     Global.ViewDetail=this;

     Bundle param=getIntent().getExtras();
        final String separate=(String) param.get("tseparate");
        final String group=(String) param.get("tgroup");
        tseparate=separate;
        tgroup=group;

        //import data utk pertama x
        final DataProcessor dbHelper = new DataProcessor(this);
        dbHelper.openDataBase();}

Comment: Post the activity code full. looks like dbHelper is null

Comment: where is dbHelper declared? Post that code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/atfTBAEZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the instance variable is never initialized

Change this

```
  final DataProcessor dbHelper = new DataProcessor(this); 
  // dbHelper is local to onCreate
  // re-declared and initialized. While the instance variable is null
```

To

```
  dbHelper = new DataProcessor(this);
```

Also change

```
  menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

to

```
  menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

Comment: @user3172337  Your Welcome.next time remember to post the relevant info. here the activity code. Atleast the relevant part

Comment: sorry, I think it is too long, waste many spaces, but many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

First correct you should change this

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
```

to

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

and reference your `listitem` in `onCreate(....)`

ans also you need to create `Object` of `dbHelper`

```
 dbHelper = new DataProcessor(this);
```

Comment: I have initialitate listitem onCreate, but I didnt write because it is too long source code, I just follow also from this tutorial, the layout menu item, I put on res/layout like this totorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

Comment: this is wrong in the tutroial, Simple Plan is right, You have to put menu layouts inside the menu-folder and reference it with R.menu.